# Capistrano 3 database migrations fail and does not create current symlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've never worked with Capistrano before and currently I am fighting the urge to just scrap it and go back to my old manual ways.

As I understand, Capistrano V3 does not create the initial database because they feel it is the duty of the DB administrator.

So I must be missing something but I have followed their instructions but the initial `cap staging deploy` fails when it gets to the `rake db:migrate` step because the database does not exist.

Because of the failure, the `symlink` for `current -> releases` never gets created.

Is it just accepted general practice that we SSH into our boxes and `cd` into the first folder under `releases` and manually run `rake db:create`...?

And then from there, am I supposed to just run `cap staging deploy` again so that it finishes creating the `symlinks`?

Seems hacky for something that is supposed to make things easier and I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly or not.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you'll only do it once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does make sense to leave certain things out of a deployment.  As the initial set up and the routine deployments are very separate functions and require different specialties, or in large deployments even different skillsets.  That said.. I'm totally with you - on the first deploy having to manually set up the database and certain files (specifically linked files like secrets.yml) is a step that just wastes my time.

I use this plugin:
https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-postgresql

just add the `require capistrano/postgresql` to your capfile as you would any plugin

then run `cap staging setup` before the first time you run `cap staging deploy`

Comment: This looks like an acceptable route, I need to customize the template because I am using `postgis` and not `postgres` directly.

Did you opt to just give sudo NOPASSWD rights?  I'm currently hitting tty issues.

Comment: @MikeGabriel -    I set certain commands to be available to the deploy user and only those commands so they can't hurt too much.    You can use cmd_alias in the sudoers file to create commands with arguments, then use   `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: COMMANDA, COMMANDB, COMMANDC`